# Jquery change background color of div when mouseover

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-ui

I try execute jquery for change background color of div , but all inside php code , and when put the mouse over this div should change color of background , but i think writte bad something and don´t get this effect finally

**My code it´s simple and it´s this :**

```
   echo '<div id="rating_poll_front" onmouseover="this.css("background-color","red")" onmouseleave="this.css("background-color","yellow");" style="background-color:yellow;"></div> ';
```

Thank´s for the help to community , Regards !!!

Comment: `this` gives the HTMLElement object which has no `.css()`. Use `$(this)` instead.

Comment: because `this` is not a jQuery object

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You should use `$(this)` because `this` returns an HTML element which didn't have the function `css()`.
Alternatively, you can use `this.style.backgroundColor=yellow`.

> Please escape or use single quote inside a set of double quote

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="rating_poll_front" onmouseover="$(this).css('background-color','red')" onmouseleave="$(this).css('background-color','yellow');" style="background-color:yellow;">dsfdsf</div>
```

In plain JavaScript

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="rating_poll_front" onmouseover="this.style.backgroundColor='red';" onmouseleave="this.style.backgroundColor='yellow';" style="background-color:yellow;">dsfdsf</div>
```

Answer (score 1):

Try using $(this) instead of this

```
echo '<div id="rating_poll_front" onmouseover="$(this).css(\'background-color\',\'red\')" onmouseleave="$(this).css(\'background-color\',\'yellow\');" style="background-color:yellow;"></div> ';
```

Answer (score 1):

**First:**

When you are using double quotes **"** in html use single quotes **'** in its attributes.

This

```
<div id="rating_poll_front" onmouseover="this.css("background-color","red")" onmouseleave="this.css("background-color","yellow");" style="background-color:yellow;"></div>
```

Should be:

```
<div id="rating_poll_front" onmouseover="this.css('background-color','red')" onmouseleave="this.css('background-color','yellow');" style="background-color:yellow;"></div>
```

**Second:**

As the php code is also using single quotes so use a backslash before the single quote inside php:

Example:

```
echo '<div id="rating_poll_front" onmouseover="this.css(\'background-color\',\'red\')" onmouseleave="this.css(\'background-color\',\'yellow\');" style="background-color:yellow;"></div>';
```

Third there is no such property as css() in javascript, use this.style.backgroundColor:

**So your code finally becomes:**

```
echo '<div id="rating_poll_front" onmouseover="this.style.backgroundColor=\'red\';" onmouseleave="this.style.backgroundColor=\'yellow\';" style="background-color:yellow;">Hello</div>';
```

When it comes to browser it will run like the snippet:

```html
<div id="rating_poll_front" onmouseover="this.style.backgroundColor='red';" onmouseleave="this.style.backgroundColor='yellow';" style="background-color:yellow;">Hello</div>
```